# "Related Questions" should be "Possible Answers," or at least "Similar Questions"

Tags: feature-request, edits, related-questions

I'm surprised the section containing related questions is called `Related Questions`, and not `Possible Answers`, `Similar Questions` or `Possible Duplicates`; `Related Questions` doesn't suggest to me they may contain the answer to my question, which is the only reason why I assume they're listed.

EDIT: Yes, as Jefromi pointed out, I am referring to the section titled `Related Questions` that appears when the focus leaves from the Title textbox while editing, not the `Related` questions on the RHS of the page.

Comment: I know you said "'related questions'", not "'related' questions", and that you used the "editing" tag, but you might want to clarify in the body of your question that you mean the ones that show up while editing a question, rather than the "Related" questions in sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no particular feelings on this, but isn't this just arguing semantics?

Comment: Yeah I tossed between [feature-request] and [bug], or even [support]: it was my point of view that it seemed wrong. [Bug] did seem a little strong, but [change-request] wasn't an option :-) And, yes, it is just arguing semantics!

Comment: Maybe not entirely. There is a clear difference between this and the sidebar related questions; it might be good for them to have different names. The sidebar tends to cover a lot of relations (potential duplicates as well as further reading), while as Mark says, the primary use for the related questions is indeed potential duplicates. I wonder if naming it as such might slightly cut down on new users glossing over it and posting obvious duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the only reason they're listed, I think that's a false assumption.  Related topics may not answer your question but may answer your *next* question or provide you info/tips that'll help on the topic you're on now and later.

Look at it this way, if your assumption was correct, why not call the section "Duplicates"?

Comment: I have taken your last as a valid suggestion and added it to the question.

Comment: @Mark: You're kind of missing the point. Yes, sometimes they could be duplicates, sometimes they're similar, sometimes they could provide an answer, and sometimes they could simply provide information on a, well, related topic. "Related" covers all the bases.

Comment: @Jefromi However if they were really designed to provide more than possible duplicates, they'd at least attempt to be updated when you fill in the content of the question.